# React - Store default component configuration to restore it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, use-state

What is the best way to store a default configuration without using contexts and use it to restore the default state of one or more components?

I use it, but I don't know if it's the best way

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

var defaultSettings;

function Component() 
{
    const [ settings, setSettings ] = useState({});
    const [ showModal, setShowModal ] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!defaultSettings)
        {
            defaultSettings = settings;
        }

        if (_.isEqual(defaultSettings, settings))
        {
            if (showModal)
            {
                setShowModal(false);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (!showModal)
            {
                setShowModal(true);
            }
        }
    }, [ settings ]);

    return (
        ...
    );
}

export default Component;
```

Comment: Use `usRef` hook.

Comment: @AjeetShah thx so much

Comment: But using a constant data outside the component (like you have in question) is fine if you are only "reading" (not writing) that data. But currently you are modifying the data, so better to use `useRef`.